# How to keep member variables or properties on nancy module's side?

Tags: c#, nancy

I would like to know if it's possible to keep member variables or public properties  under a `NancyModule`.

Here's a simple example of what I think should work but doesn't.

```
public class MyModule : NancyModule
{
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; } = new List<string>();//Problem

    public MyModule()
    {
        #region Get
        Get("/index", args => GetIndex("user"));
        #endregion

        #region Post
        Post("/postUser", args => PostUser("user"));
        #endregion
    }

    private int GetIndex(string user)
    {
        return MyList.IndexOf(user);//Problem
    }

    private int PostUser(string user)
    {
        MyList.Add(user);//Problem

        return MyList.IndexOf(user);//Problem
    }
}
```

Through debugging, I saw that every time I send a `POST` or a `GET` to my running `NancyHost`, the whole `NancyModule` is parsed or recalled... So I think my list is reset to a new list of strings every time.

I'm kinda new to nancy and I'm definitely doing something wrong. Is it even possible keep such a variable within this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `MyList` static.

`public static List<string> MyList { get; set; } = new List<string>();`

An instance of each NancyModule is created at startup and then as HTTP requests come in an instance of the NancyModule that should handle the request is created. So yes, a new instance of your module is created per request. That means that sharing state between requests must be done by other means that instance variable/properties - could be a database, could be static variables.

Comment: That's just what I needed! (:

Comment: This is crazy - why is the module being recreated per request? I've just been caught out by this - my class must be single instance and making it static is an ugly solution. I'll move to another library because this is just a terrible design.